# Xamarin Html label scrollable

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im making a novel reader app.

And i have a html which is the chapter.

I have made a custom htmlLabel that will containe tha html

The problem is that the size of the label is only as big as the screan all other text stay hidden

I have the label inside a scrollview but even so it only expand to the size of the screan for some reasion

Here is my custom label renderer.
Now i know i could use a webview but i still want a label instead.

```
sing System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Support.V4.Text;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Widget;
using Comic.Viewer.Controllers;
using Comic.Viewer.Droid.Renderer;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ClickableHtmlLabel), typeof(ClickableHtmlLabelRenderer))]
namespace Comic.Viewer.Droid.Renderer
{
   public class ClickableHtmlLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        public ClickableHtmlLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }


        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control?.SetText(HtmlCompat.FromHtml(Element.Text, HtmlCompat.FromHtmlModeLegacy), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                Control?.SetText(HtmlCompat.FromHtml(Element.Text, HtmlCompat.FromHtmlModeLegacy), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
            }

            var el = Element as ClickableHtmlLabel;
            this.Click += new EventHandler((o, sender) =>
            {
                el.Clicked();

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a Label control is probably not the right choice for multi page text

Comment: what is there other then webview then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use custom renderer to create `HtmlLabel`. And then put the `HtmlLabel` inside a `ScrollView`. It would make the `HtmlLabel` scrollable. I make a code sample for your reference.

HtmlLabel.cs

```
public class HtmlLabel : Label
{
}
```

HtmlLabelRenderer.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HtmlLabel), typeof(HtmlLabelRenderer))]
namespace XamarinDemo.Droid.Renderers
{
 class HtmlLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
 {
    public HtmlLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null && e.NewElement != null)
        {
            UpdateText();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(HtmlLabel.Text))
        {
            UpdateText();
        }
    }

    void UpdateText()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Element?.Text))
        {
            Control.Text = string.Empty;
            return;
        }

        Control.TextFormatted = Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N
            ? Html.FromHtml(Element.Text, FromHtmlOptions.ModeCompact)
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            : Html.FromHtml(Element.Text);
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete

        Control.MovementMethod = Android.Text.Method.LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
     }
  }
```

Uasge:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <control:HtmlLabel x:Name="htmlLabel" FontSize="Large"/>
    </ScrollView>
 </ContentPage.Content>
```

Set the html text.

```
  htmlLabel.Text = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Starting.</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>Ending.</p>

</body>
</html>";
```

[image]

Comment: Hi is there a renderer for IOS?